# C# PostSharp cannot resolve the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

I have a C# project, that is using PostSharp and is buidling fine.
I wanted to create a copy of this project with references to the same files, but it's resolving in issues with referenced assemblies.
Referenced assembly is in place (try to add/remove it few times), but for some reason version of the found assembly (on the right location) is 0.0.0.0. I searched in web and all solutions suggested to use property PostSharpTargetFrameworkVersion 4.0 in .csproj. This unfortunately didn't solve my problem. Do you maybe have an idea? Here is log message from postsharp:

```
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: Unhandled exception (4.3.20.0, postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.460798, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'myapplication.remote, version=2.0.0.22787, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null'.
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: ============ PostSharp Assembly Loading Log ===================
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Finding the assembly with binding identity 'myapplication.remote', version=2.0.0.22787, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null'.
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Found file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyApplication\MyApplication.Remote.dll' with identity ', version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null, processorarchitecture=msil'.
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Reference mismatch for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyApplication\MyApplication.Remote.dll' [None].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.3.20\bin.Release\MyApplication.Remote.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.3.20\bin.Release\MyApplication.Remote.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.3.20\bin.Release\MyApplication.Remote.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\MyFiles\Test\Server\bin\Debug\MyApplication.Remote.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Found file 'D:\MyFiles\Test\Server\bin\Debug\MyApplication.Remote.dll' with identity ', version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null, processorarchitecture=msil'.
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Reference mismatch for 'D:\MyFiles\Test\Server\bin\Debug\MyApplication.Remote.dll' [None].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\MyFiles\Test\Server\bin\Debug\MyApplication.Remote.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\MyFiles\Test\Server\obj\Debug\MyApplication.Remote.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\MyFiles\Test\Server\obj\Debug\MyApplication.Remote.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\MyFiles\Test\Server\obj\Debug\MyApplication.Remote.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
..........
```

Comment: Well the problem is that you are searching for assembly with a specific version (i.e. your project has such reference) but actual assembly has lower version. PostSharp is more strict than C# compiler in this regard. You can either try PostSharp 5.1.1-preview which remedies a lot of these problems (for a different reason though) or use `assemblyBinding` in `app.config` to map the version manually. In general the fact that one of assemblies has reference to version `2.0.0.22787`, while the actual assembly has `0.0.0.0` is a bit odd.

Comment: Hi, I referenced exactly that one assembly, that is recognized as version 0.0.0.0 in the end. I tried to update PostSharp but either it didn't work with current code anymore, or the same error occurred. In my opinion, the fact that the version 0.0.0.0 is recognized is saying that PostSharp cannot read the library. But I have no clue where the problem could be.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Could you please report this as a bug on PostSharp Support site? We would really appreciate a reproduction of this issue.